# Want to show total of amount

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using `react-table` for binding data in grid.
Now I have to show 4 columns and one column has value of amount(price).

So in footer I want to show total of that price.

Can any one please help me on this?

Here is my sample code

```
<ReactTable
                columns={columns}
                noDataText="No rows found"
                manual // Forces table not to paginate or sort automatically, so we can handle it server-side
                data={this.props.drinkList}
                loading={this.props.loading}
                showPagination={true}
                page={this.state.page > 0 ? this.state.page : 0}
                showPaginationTop={false}
                pages={pageCount}
                showPaginationBottom={true}
                defaultPageSize={10}
                sortable={false}
                pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]}
                onFetchData={(state, instance) => {
                  this.setState({ page: state.page });
                  this.props.getDrinkListAction(
                    this.props.location.state.barId,
                    this.props.location.state.businessId,
                    this.state.searchText,
                    state.page + 1,
                    localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    state.pageSize,
                    history
                  );
                }}
/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure. And please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code snippet of your attempt and then we can start.

Comment: yes I have added my code

Answer (score 1):

if you use `react-table` latest. On place your `TableBody` code you can do like this:

```
<ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age",
              Footer: (
                <span>
                  <strong>Sum:</strong> {this.computeSum(data, "age")}
                </span>
              )
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
```

and `computeSum` function:

```
computeSum = (arr, totalFieldName) => {
  const { length } = arr;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    count += Number((typeof arr[i][totalFieldName] === 'object')
      ? arr[i][totalFieldName].name : arr[i][totalFieldName] || 0);
  }
  return count;
};
```

Comment: I have used this one "react-table": "^6.10.3",

Comment: then u can check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6/examples/footers) example from officially docs.

Comment: Yes I think it can help, but its for average, for sum what I need to use?

Comment: You can change ```avg``` function like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-night-wb5y3). I think it will be helpful for you!

Comment: @IPS I changed my code according your ```react-table``` version.

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: if everything will be ok, than confirm this answer :)